# What is the use of the sentinel method in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have seen [sentinel](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET) methods being used while setting foreign relationship to users.

What exactly are these methods used for?

Comment: it seems that function which was defined at a higher (upper lines) global scope, is going to create or get a user object with username equal to 'deleted', and then SET would use that user.

Answer (score 3):

Sentinel objects are used to avoid leaving orphaned objects when their referenced object gets deleted. Consider a user that posts comments, if you want to keep their comments after they delete their account, you could SET a sentinel user to the comments' user field instead of NULL.